# Is there any attribute in <p:dialog> so that next events will take place only after selecting values in that dialog box

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to display a dialog box, where Yes and No commandButtons present.The problem iam facing is, after the dialog rendered,the background actions are still functioning like scrolling or selecting values outside the dialog box.

I want to restrict those background actions. Only if commandButtons inside dialog are selected,next actions should take place.I hope you guys understand my problem.

EDITED:
Code:

```
<p:dialog  widgetVar="shutdownProductWidgetVar"             
                width="900px" blockScroll="true"
                style="height: 450px;
                        left: 170px;
                        top: 50px;
                        display: block;
                        position:fixed;
                        border-bottom: 2px solid #5179c9 !important;"   
                styleClass="overflowDialog popUpHeader popUpHeaderTitle" 
                resizable="false" draggable="false" responsive="true"
                showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" fitViewport="true"
                closeOnEscape="true" appendToBody="true"
                modal="true"  onShow="PF('shutdownProductWidgetVar').initPosition()">
```

**Before** the pop up renders:UI be like
[image]

**After** the pop up renders:UI be like
[image]

I cant restrict the background activity and also dialog box renders like this.Kindly help me out.

Comment: sounds like modal=true

Comment: i have used that attriute also